# Properties of a non-invertible square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am wondering what properties does $A$, an $n\times n$ non invertible matrix, have.

An obvious one is $\det(A)=0$

But, I am not sure about other intuitions that I am having. For example:

$rank(A) < n$

$null(A) > 0$

And what about it's eigenvalues and eigenvectors, is there anything we can tell about them beforhand?

Comment: Nothing.  Invertibility and diagonalisability are two distinct concepts.  A square matrix have be neither, either one, or both properties.  The zero matrix is singular but diagonalisable.  An identity matrix has both properties.  You may find some non-diagonalisable matrices...

Comment: Who said anything about it being diagonalizable? All I wanted to know were direct implications of it being non-invertible. :p

Comment: That's just my reflex upon seeing eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [invertible matrix theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem) gives a rather long list of necessary and sufficient conditions for a matrix to be an invertible matrix.  As a result, a matrix is noninvertible can be summed up by the same list with each entry negated.

The start of such a list might read:

Given an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, the following are equivalent statements:

- $A$ is a noninvertible matrix
- $\det(A)=0$
- $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$
- $rank(A)<n$
- the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent
- the rows of $A$ are linearly dependent
- $A$ cannot be row reduced to the identity matrix
- $\vdots$
  -

Answer (score 1):

For sure A has one zero eigenvalue and an associated subspace of eigenvectors with dimension greater than one (depending in geometric multeplicity of $\lambda =0$).

Thus of course $rank(A)<n$ and $null(A)>0$ such that $rank(A)+null(A)=n$.